# Saving in PNG (using PIL library) after taking ImageChops.difference of two PNG files is producing transparent (or white) PNG image file

Tags: python, image, png, python-imaging-library

Here in this code I am taking difference of two same resolution PNG images ,then saving the difference,. Saving in JPEG works fine but in PNG, it produces a total tranparent PNG image file. look at the comments in the last two lines

```
import Image
import ImageChops
js_black_im = Image.open("/js_black.png")
js_white_im = Image.open("/fb_white.png")
diff_im = ImageChops.difference(js_black_im, js_white_im)
diff_im.save("/js_onlytext.jpeg", "JPEG") #this works as expected
diff_im.save("/js_onlytext.png", "PNG") #this produces a total tranparent PNG image file![js_black.png][1]![fb_black.png][2]
```

Comment: The original images have an alpha channel?

Comment: original images are screenshots of webpage (facebook login page) taken via selenium. I dont know if they have alpha channels

Comment: Id' try adding a `convert('RGB')`, eg `ImageChops.difference(js_black_im, js_white_im).convert('RGB')`

Comment: yes, It works now. This is the answer. Can you please explain or give directions why it produced transparent PNG before but after converting to RGB, it produced expected image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your original images have an alpha channel (RGBA), you should know that beforehand, and/or check the result the image type that Image.open produces (looking at `Image.mode` or `Image.info`). Anyway, you can force the RGB type (no alpha channel) by calling `<image>.convert('RGB')`, before or after doing the difference.

Comment: yes its RGBA
<PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1353x854 at 0xB73CCD6C>
and the difference is also RGBA
<Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=1353x854 at 0xB73FED8C>
So why do we need to force Difference RGBA to RGB inorder to make it display as expected and not transparent?

Comment: If the original images are RGBA, they have an alpha channel; supposing they are fully opaque, then alpha=255 for all pixels. When you do the difference, PIL substract also that channel, so you get alpha=0, which means fully transparent (at least this is what I guess)